# What is the "undef" object of Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In the [MRI implementation of gc.c](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/gc.c#3167) I saw an object named `undef`. What is that `undef` object? What is its class? How can I access it? Is there any utility for it?

Comment: I don't know what it is, but it's probably not related to the `undef` method used to undefine a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an educated guess on my part, maybe Matz will see this question at some point and give us a definitive answer, hopefully this will do in the meantime.

As you might know, ruby was somewhat influenced by perl at least early on (which is why we have variables like $@ and $_ etc.). Perl has an `undef` keyword/function (e.g. if you declare a variable without initialising - its value is undefined). I would say, that at some time in the past Ruby was also meant to have something similar (i.e. variables would be able to have an undefined value). How do we know this? By the context in which it is found.

As you can see, that comment describes how the `object_id` of the various Ruby objects is derived. Some details on that can be found [here](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2006/01/the_ruby_value_1.html). But, in essence we know the following:

```
false.object_id == 0
true.object_id == 2
nil.object_id == 4
```

This is what the comment suggests and this is indeed the case, you can crack open an `irb` session and try it out for yourself. It looks like `undef` was meant to have an `object_id` of 6.

Now, `undef` is indeed a reserved word in Ruby, but it is not a special object like `nil`, `false` and `true`, it is - as we know - a keyword used to undefine a method.

So, to answer your question, there is no `undef` object, it has no class and you can't access it. The purpose that `undef` was meant to serve is instead being served by the `nil` object in the Ruby that we know today. But, it has remained in the code as a legacy of times gone by, for the more curious of us to find and puzzle over.

Comment: I found it isn't an object because I can't retrieve one with `ObjectSpace._id2ref(6)`. It's found on [many places](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?i=Qundef), and [here](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/include/ruby/ruby.h#352) it is refered as "undefined value for placeholder". In fact, it is used to represent undefined (or null) values instead of 0, -1, NULL etc. It seems to be necessary to avoid to conflict with any valid Ruby object. A good example is to [invalidate removed instance variables](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/variable.c#1279).

Comment: And +1 for your link about values. Thank you! :)

Comment: In that last example it looks to me like Qundef is being used to overwrite the value of the instance variable that is being removed. It must be necessary in order for Ruby to throw an exception if you try to access that instance variable. If they simply used Qnil then my guess is you wouldn't get an exception but would instead get nil coming back as the return value which is not the behaviour you want. Very interesting, I quite enjoyed looking into this - good question.

Comment: I can't get an exception by trying to access an undefined (or removed) instance variable - it silently returns `nil` (v. 1.8.7).

Comment: You're right, I am getting the same on 1.9.2 - weird (although on second look, the example in the comments does show that :)). Maybe Qundef is simply used to overwrite the memory location with some random garbage, or maybe point the pointer to some known location/value (more likely). I wish someone from the Ruby core team would come along and put us out of our misery :).

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure this is referring to an undefined variable (as opposed to a variable defined as `nil`).

Take a look at this:

```
def hello(object = 'World')
  puts "Hello #{object}"
end

hello                 #=> 'Hello World'
hello 'stackoverflow' #=> 'Hello stackoverflow'
hello nil             #=> 'Hello '
```

**EDIT:**
To conclude with a more complete answer to your question. You will never be able to access that `undef` object. It only exists in the method definition, not in its body. Either it is filled with a default value (like `'World'` above) or you will get an `ArgumentError` because you didn't specify all method parameters.

Comment: Ah, it took a minute to grasp your answer to me. There is a difference between passing no argument at all to a method and passing `nil`. That difference is the `undef` object. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Correct, default argument values take only precedence if literally no value is passed.